# How to execute javascript in different file?

Tags: javascript, html, file, onclick

I have multiple javascript functions in my html page. One of them, by far the biggest, is executed on a button click. If I moved that function into a separate .js file, what would be the syntax to have the onclick run that file?

Comment: Just make sure the script file is loaded before you try to use the functions defined within it. With jquery, for example, you'd wrap your calling code within a `$(function () { /* here */ });`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name of the function is still the same, then you don't have to do anything except include the script in your html somewhere before any code uses it, like so:

```
<script src="/yourscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your javascript functions can be in any number of files. You just need to add the reference to the .js file like this inside the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/scripts/filename.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to change anything.**

Just include your javascript file in your `HEAD` section, and the rest may remain the same. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` doesn't run the file.  It runs the function contained within that file.  You wouldn't need to change the `onclick` syntax to make that happen.

Comment: Would be nice if the down-voter would say what's wrong with my answer.